# 3 dimensional Laplacian with 4 non-homogeneous boundary conditions

Tags: differential-equations, equation-solving, calculus-and-analysis, boundary-conditions

I have the 3-D Laplacian ($\nabla^2 T(x,y,z)=0$) defined over $x\in[0,L], y\in[0,l], z\in[0,w]$ with four non-homogeneous boundary conditions as follows:

$$T(0,y,z)=t_{hi}\tag1$$
$$T(x,0,z)=t_{ci}\tag2$$
$$\frac{\partial T(x,y,0)}{\partial z}=p_c\Bigg(T(x,y,0)-e^{\frac{-b_c y}{l}}\bigg(t_{ci}+\frac{b_c}{l}\int_0^y e^{\frac{b_c s}{l}} T(x,s,0)\mathrm{d}s\bigg)\Bigg)\tag 3$$
$$\frac{\partial T(x,y,w)}{\partial z}=p_h\Bigg(e^{\frac{-b_h x}{L}}\bigg(t_{hi}+\frac{b_h}{L}\int_0^x e^{\frac{b_h s}{L}} T(s,y,w)\mathrm{d}s\bigg)-T(x,y,w)\Bigg)\tag 4$$
$$\frac{\partial T(L,y,z)}{\partial x}=0\tag 5$$
$$\frac{\partial T(x,l,z)}{\partial y}=0\tag 6$$

To handle these four non-homogeneous condition, I tried an approach where i split the problem into three parts ; each for one direction and then I added the respective solutions. While splitting, except for the non-homogeneous condition, all other faces were considered homogeneous Dirichlet.

But the results i got were nonsensical, like the presence of a z-plane at a higher temperature than the planes at $z=0$ and $z=L$.

$\beta_h,\beta_c,p_h,p_c,t_{hi},t_{ci}$ are all constants.

I tried the following code. T1 and T2 are the sub problems in the $x$ and $y$ directions while T3 is in the $z$ direction using which along with bc 3 and 4 I determined the constants for T3 using bc 3 and 4.

```
T1[x_, y_, z_] = ((16 thi E^(\[Gamma] x) (1 + E^(2 \[Gamma] (L - x))))/(k j \[Pi]^2 (1 + E^(2 \[Gamma] L))))*Sin[k \[Pi] y/l]*Sin[j \[Pi] z/w];
T2[x_, y_, z_] = ((16 tci E^(\[Gamma] y) (1 + E^(2 \[Gamma] (l - y))))/(k j \[Pi]^2 (1 + E^(2 \[Gamma] l))))*Sin[k \[Pi] x/L]*Sin[j \[Pi] z/w];
T3[x_, y_, z_] = (Subscript[C, 1] E^(\[Gamma] z) + Subscript[C, 2] E^(- \[Gamma] z))*Sin[k \[Pi] x/L]*Sin[j \[Pi] y/l]
```

**Can there be some other way of solving this Laplacian without splitting up the problem in three different parts ?**

**NOTE** *Context* 
The actual form of b.c. $(2),(3)$ are
$$\frac{\partial T(x,y,0)}{\partial z}=p_c(T(x,y,0)-t_c(x,y))$$

$$\frac{\partial T(x,y,w)}{\partial z}=p_h(t_h(x,y)-T(x,y,w))$$

where $t_h$ and $t_c$ comes from the following equations

$$\frac{\partial t_h}{\partial x}+\frac{b_h}{L} (t_h-T(x,y,w))=0$$

$$\frac{\partial t_c}{\partial y}+\frac{b_c}{l} (T(x,y,0)-t_c)=0$$

$t_h(x=0)=t_{hi}$ and $t_c(y=0)=t_{ci}$ is known.

Comment: That is the standard way to do it.  You can't satisfy all boundary conditions in one swoop.  You should check each of your three solutions separately with numerical values to make sure each was done correctly.  When all three are correct, adding them must be correct for the whole solution.

Comment: @BillWatts The problem here describes two fluids flowing orthogonal to each other on either side of a cuboidal wall (at $z=0$ and $z=\mu$) and in thermal interaction with each other though the wall. On solving the problem by sub-dividing it into three parts (each for a particular direction), the final superimposed solution shows a $z-$plane which is at a higher temperature than both the $z=0$ plane (exposed to the cold fluid) and $z=\mu$ plane (exposed to the hot fluid). This is what bugs me as the highest temperature should be on the $z=\mu$ surface. It is known that $t_{hi}>t_{ci}$.